# How to pass special characters in the urls in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Suppose I want to pass the username in the url:

```
username  = 'kakar@gmail.com'
```

So in the urls, its like this:

```
url(r'(?P<user_name>\w+)/$', 'user_related.views.profile', name='profile'),
```

And to fetch that user, in the views.py:

```
def profile(request, user_name):
    user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)

    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {'user':user})
```

But I get an error:

```
User matching query does not exist.
```

Because django automatically converts `@` into `%40`. How can I pass the actual `username` to the view? Please help me solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [unquote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) function from standard `urllib` module:

```
from urllib import unquote

user = User.objects.get(username=unquote(user_name))
```

BTW, as far as I understand regex in your url() should be `[\w@%.]+`.  Plain `\w+` do not match `kakar@gmail.com` and `kakar%40gmail.com`.

Comment: Perfect!!! I was still getting an error `User matching query does not exist`, but your edit helped me! Thank you! However just wondering, what's the use of `%` in the urls, since it will only take `@`?

Comment: '@' has a special meaning in urls (http://user:passwd@example.com) so in "URI" RFC it is recommended to encode `@` as `%40`. But AFAIK in real life you can safely use `@` in URL path.

Comment: This answer's a life saver! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Notice that in Python3, unquote is now at urllib.parse, so if using Python3 replace `from urllib import unquote` with `from urllib.parse import unquote`

Answer (score 3):

The existing answer is missing a couple things, but I don't have enough rep to comment or edit it.  Here is a working solution:

For function based views:

In `views.py`:

```
# this is incorrect for current versions of Django in the other answer
from urllib.parse import unquote

def profile(request, user_name):
    user = User.objects.get(username=unquote(user_name))
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {'user':user})
```

Then, in `urls.py`, we can skip regex altogether:

```
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/<str:user_name>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    # ... put more urls here...
]
```

That's pretty much it for function based views.  But I am using class based views, which look a tiny bit different.  Here is what I did to get this working with class based views:

In `views.py`:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class Profile(DetailView):
    """Display the user's profile"""
    template_name = 'user_profile.html'
    model = User

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = kwargs['user_name']
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(username=unquote(self.username))
        except:
            raise Http404
```

And when using class based views, your `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/<str:user_name>/', views.Profile.as_view(), name='profile'),
    # ... put more urls here...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the string by using `w`

`url(r'^url_name/(?P<param_name>[\w\@%-+]+)/$',url_method,name='end_point_name')`